# Sonarqube service failed to start in Linux Server

Tags: sonarqube

We are using sonarqube-5.3 running in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6. After starting the service, it automatically goes down with below Error. Please guide me to fix this issue.

Error Logs

```
2017.12.07 17:28:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
2017.12.07 17:28:36 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletCont
extListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value of index field is null: login
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:89) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.execute(IndexSynchronizer.java:95) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:78) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:197) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value of index field is null: login
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value of index field is null: login
        at org.sonar.server.search.BaseDoc.getField(BaseDoc.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.index.UserDoc.login(UserDoc.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.index.UserIndexer.newUpsertRequest(UserIndexer.java:69) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.index.UserIndexer.doIndex(UserIndexer.java:61) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.index.UserIndexer.doIndex(UserIndexer.java:48) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$2.index(BaseIndexer.java:92) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$1.run(BaseIndexer.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
2017.12.07 17:28:36 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_71-b15 [linux-amd64]
2017.12.07 17:28:36 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2017.12.07 17:28:40 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
```

Comment: What is changed? You should plan to update to a LTS version

Comment: Indeed, you you try on SonarQube 6.7